# Not getting total records from the database

Tags: java, mysql

I have 4 records in my database table, but i am getting only one record from the function. please check my code once. When i call the getMaterialTransferRecords() function inside this function i have another function getMaterialUnit(). I am not able to find the solution. Please any one help me.

This is the query i am executing in my sqlyog. please check it once

[image]

Above is my query and below is the result.

This is how i am calling the function.

```
// Fetch Data from User Table
        int startPageIndex = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("jtStartIndex"));
        int recordsPerPage = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("jtPageSize"));

        String jtSorting = request.getParameter("jtSorting");
        MaterialTransferUtils utils = new MaterialTransferUtils();
        //System.out.println("Cash Purchases Start Page Index:"+startPageIndex+" recordsPerPage:"+recordsPerPage);

        if(jtSorting != null)
        {
            jtSorting = jtSorting.replaceAll("material_destn_code", "material_destn_code");
            jtSorting = jtSorting.replaceAll("date", "transferred_on");
        }
        // Fetch Data from Cash Memo Table
        mtList = utils.getMaterialTransferRecords(startPageIndex, recordsPerPage,jtSorting);
```

Please check the code once.

```
public List<MaterialTransferBean> getMaterialTransferRecords(int startPageIndex, int recordsPerPage,String jtSorting)
{
    List<MaterialTransferBean> list = new ArrayList<MaterialTransferBean>();
    con=com.s2s.bssb.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    MaterialTransferBean mtbean = null;

    String sortStr = "material_destn_code DESC";
    if(null != jtSorting)
        sortStr = jtSorting;

    String query = "SELECT sno,material_loc_code,transferred_on,mr_no,do_no,material_destn_code,material_id,quantity,unit_price, "
            + "gst,remarks FROM material_transfer ORDER BY "+sortStr+" LIMIT "+recordsPerPage+" offset "+startPageIndex+"";

    System.out.println(query);

    if(con!=null){
        try{
            ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                MaterialTransferBean bean = new MaterialTransferBean();
                bean.setSno(rs.getInt("sno"));
                bean.setMaterial_loc_code(rs.getString("material_loc_code"));
                bean.setDate(rs.getDate("transferred_on"));
                bean.setMr_no(rs.getString("mr_no"));
                bean.setDo_no(rs.getString("do_no"));
                bean.setMaterial_destn_code(rs.getString("material_destn_code"));
                bean.setQuantity(rs.getDouble("quantity"));
                bean.setUnit_price(rs.getDouble("unit_price"));
                bean.setAmount(rs.getDouble("quantity")*rs.getDouble("unit_price"));
                bean.setGst(((rs.getDouble("quantity")*rs.getDouble("unit_price"))*(rs.getDouble("gst")))/100);
                bean.setTtl_amount((rs.getDouble("quantity")*rs.getDouble("unit_price"))+(((rs.getDouble("quantity")*rs.getDouble("unit_price"))*(rs.getDouble("gst")))/100));
                bean.setRemarks(rs.getString("remarks"));

                mtbean = new MaterialTransferBean();

                mtbean = getMaterialUnit(rs.getInt("material_id"));

                bean.setMaterial(mtbean.getMaterial());
                bean.setUnit(mtbean.getUnit());

                list.add(bean);
            }
            rs.close();
            com.s2s.bssb.database.ConnectionDB.close(con);
            com.s2s.bssb.database.ConnectionDB.close(ps, con);
        }catch(SQLException sql_ex){
            sql_ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Connection Not Created");
    }

    return list;
}

public MaterialTransferBean getMaterialUnit(int material_id){
    MaterialTransferBean bean = null;
     con=com.s2s.bssb.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        String query = "select material,unit from materials where id=?";

        if(con!=null){
            try{
                ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setInt(1, material_id);
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    bean = new MaterialTransferBean();
                    bean.setMaterial(rs.getString("material"));
                    bean.setUnit(rs.getString("unit"));
                }
            }catch(SQLException sql_ex){
                sql_ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: What is `recordsPerPage` and `startPageIndex`?  Actually, which SELECT are you talking about?

Comment: SELECT sno,material_loc_code,transferred_on,mr_no,do_no,material_destn_code,material_id,quantity,unit_price, gst,remarks FROM material_transfer ORDER BY material_destn_code DESC LIMIT 3 offset 0  , this is the query i am executing there

Comment: Have you tried running the same command using the MySql client?

Comment: those are my function parameters

Comment: Sorry, I meant what are their values, but you've stated them in your earlier comment.

Comment: yes. i tried. its working in mysql client.

Comment: Can you please post the data in the database and the result (and the query) when you execute it directly in MySql?... also let us see how do you call the method getMaterialTransferRecords